# Database insertion troubles because of character (')

Tags: c#, sql, asp-classic

If you try to insert a string in the database containing the character `(')`, you will face a problem.

```
SQL ="Insert into mytable (name) values ('"&Request("name")&"') "
```

The solution for beginners is

```
SQL ="Insert into mytable (name) values (Replace('"&Request("name")&"',"'","@") "
```

for example then you will have to change it back when retrieving this record.

BUT, the problem is what if I have large amount of these fields that might contain this character `(')`, will i follow this time-consuming solution for every field?! or maybe any of you have a smart and quick solution?

Comment: You will definitely have problems if you build your sql query by concatenating strings. Use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection.

Comment: Tim has the only answer to this.  Especially when using values from a web request, this is dangerous and buggy.  You'll have a lot of trouble filtering out anything which will break this, so just use parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
As now stated in some comments, a way to do what is suggested could be the following.

First, fetch all of your values and store them in variables. Then create a insert statement using parameters to insert your values to the database.

```
var value1 = //fetch what you want to insert
var value2 = //fetch what you want to insert

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (@value1, @value2)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", value1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", value2);
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    }
}
```